# I have an error while installing GraghLab Create

Tags: python-2.7, pip, graphlab, turi

I'm trying to install GraphLab Create from Turi using anaconda 4.0.0 and python 2.7 as mentioned in the installation guide here https://turi.com/download/install-graphlab-create-command-line.html

but i get an encoding error as shown in the image. [image]

Comment: Do your registered email address or product key contain non-ascii characters?

Comment: product key format is like this: 9051-8A76-554B-DE1C

Comment: Please paste the text instead of using a screenshot. It's also more readable.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the mistake. I found that i was copying and pasting the product key and the email to the console, and this made some error while pasting. So make sure to type the email and product key by yourself if you encountered the same problem.